# GAE-Sessions: Where is settings.py?

Tags: google-app-engine, session

I'm using GAE-Sessions with Google App Engine. In the [readme file](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions#readme) it says "If you want to gae-sessions with Django, add 'gaesessions.DjangoSessionMiddleware' to your list of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py file." Problem is I don't have a "settings.py" file, nor is one created when a App Engine project is created. What settings.py file is GAE-Sessions referring to?

Comment: I'm using the version of Django (1.2) that's integrated with Google App Engine.

Comment: @yourfriendzak But are you actually using the Django framework, or just parts of it such as templates?

Comment: Just parts of it...the templating system and a few imports (like simplejson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) with google appengine django. What I have is a file in the same level as app.yaml which I call it appengine config.

The contents are

```
from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware
import logging

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key="ExampleofarandomKEYforcookieswritewhatyouwant")
    return app
```

In the same level I have also placed the gaesessions folder with the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Download [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) and use the `django-admin.py` helper to create all the boilerplate project, including `settings.py` file.

Documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html).

Comment: But there's already a version of Django integrated with GAE...can I just create my own settings.py and have GAE's Django use it?